# Android - Rounded square line progress bar

Tags: android, line, android-progressbar, rounded-corners

I'm trying to create a rounded square line progress bar to draw a progress around an image.

[image]

So far, I have the following XML which defines my rounded square line:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="6dp"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light" />

    <padding
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />

    <corners android:radius="50dp" />

</shape>
```

I'm aware of this solution: https://github.com/mrwonderman/android-square-progressbar but I'm not interested in as the effect is not the one I want.

I've tried to create a plain circle on top of the rounded square line and tried to merge the two with PorterDuff, but so far I was also not able to create the progress bar effect. Drawing a pie of that circle to draw the progress.

I've also tried to create the rounded square programaticaly in case the XML inflating was considered as a plain image and all pixels were taken into account during the PorterDuff merge. But same result.

Comment: create your custom `Drawable` class that will be used when calling `setProgressDrawable`

Comment: @pskink , yes thanks but how to draw the correct progress effect on the line ?

Comment: did you create a custom Drawable class? What problens do you have when drawing round rect?

Comment: For now, I have only a View class which is converting the XML drawable into bitmap and then I try to draw on that bitmap to create the desired effect (infinite post loop incrementing again and again the progress). The problem is that I didn't find so far the correct way to draw the progress effect. The solution in the mrwonderman library seems for me not applicable there as I have rounded corner and seems also not very convenient to implement. Thx

Comment: no cusom View,  you have to create custom Drawable class

Comment: How this will help me to draw on top of the existing drawable ? Not sure to understand the path you want me to take. Thx.

Comment: first read full `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable` documentation, then try [this](http://pastebin.com/uUucK6qm) simple custom `Drawable`

Comment: Sorry for late reply pskink. Thx for your response, but the piece of code you shared is to draw a plain rounded square. I have no difficulties to draw a line rounded square as shown on the first picture. Either by XML or Programmaticaly. What I want to acheive is the progress effect on that line.

Comment: Yes it draws me a half plain rounded rectangle.

Comment: ok,  so define "progress effect" is it calling `setProgress` again and again wuth different progress parameter?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you are thinking to have a standard ProgressBar with a Custom drawable: setProgressDrawable. And changes of progress call a setLevel from the Drawable ?

Comment: so what is "progress effect"? animating the progress,  e. g.  from 0 to max value? if so,  just use ObjectAnimator for that

Comment: as simple as [this](http://pastebin.com/iAXHsfPt)

Comment: This is the kind of effect I want to acheive: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/P2qTq/ not an horrizontal progressbar.

Comment: so you have the JS sources, what stops you from porting it to android `Canvas` API?

Comment: I just fint it, I will try to convert it and post it as a solution if it is working.

Comment: here you have simple solution to start with: http://pastebin.com/p3LNt4Jg

Comment: Man that's awesome. Thx. That will be def a very good point to start with.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try this simple custom class:

```
class V extends View {
    Path path = new Path();
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    float length;
    float[] intervals = {0, 0};

    public V(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        path.reset();
        RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        float inset = paint.getStrokeWidth();
        rect.inset(inset, inset);

        path.addRoundRect(rect, 100, 100, Path.Direction.CW);
        length = new PathMeasure(path, false).getLength();
        intervals[0] = intervals[1] = length;
        PathEffect effect = new DashPathEffect(intervals, length);
        paint.setPathEffect(effect);
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        PathEffect effect = new DashPathEffect(intervals, length - length * progress / 100);
        paint.setPathEffect(effect);
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    }
}
```

test code (put in inside `Activity#onCreate`):

```
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    SeekBar sb = new SeekBar(this);
    ll.addView(sb);
    final V v = new V(this);
    ll.addView(v);
    setContentView(ll);

    SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener sbcl = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            v.setProgress(progress);
        }
        @Override public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
        @Override public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
    };
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(sbcl);
```