# How to create a roundend rectangle corner progressbar with gradient?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-drawable, android-progressbar

I want to create a **rounded corners progressbar** which shows progress with **gradient colors** as shown in the image below. The progressbar will be shown as a border of an imageview and it will show the progress percentage when I will upload an image.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Rounded square line progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507926/android-rounded-square-line-progress-bar)