# Square Progressive Bar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-progressbar

I’m developing an android app in java. The app should be a "modern" timer.

Right now I have a graphical interface with a circular progress bar.

```
    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/clockbar"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="424dp"
            android:layout_height="425dp"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/circularprogressbardesign"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.538"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This is the design of the progress bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:fromDegrees="-90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="270"
    <shape
        android:shape="ring"
        android:useLevel="false">
        <gradient
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:centerColor="#00fd1d1d"
            android:endColor="@color/orange"
            android:startColor="#00fd1d1d"
/>


    </shape>

</rotate>
```

So the current aspect of the progress bar is this:

[Circular progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgcqa.png)

I would like to create a kind of empty square, with the bar flowing in the edges.

[Square-like form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m0dQ.png)

How could i do?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409912/how-to-create-a-horizontal-loading-progress-bar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507926/android-rounded-square-line-progress-bar there's a lot of reference out there, check it out

Comment: i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507926/android-rounded-square-line-progress-bar?noredirect=1&lq=1) is what you want

Comment: thanks is not exactly what I was looking for but surely there are many things that I needed